# Don't truncate columns output

Tags: python, pandas

I am setting the `options` like this

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

When I try to print the `DataFrame`, I get truncated columns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index(['contractSymbol', 'strike', 'currency', 'lastPrice', 'change', 'volume',
       'bid', 'ask', 'contractSize', 'lastTradeDate', 'impliedVolatility',
       'inTheMoney', 'openInterest', 'percentChange'],
      dtype='object')
                                   contractSymbol   strike currency  \
symbol expiration optionType                                          
TSLA   2022-12-30 calls       TSLA221230C00050000    50.00      USD   
                  calls       TSLA221230C00065000    65.00      USD
```

How do I show all columns in one row?

Comment: I generally set width some something really wide like `pd.options.display.width = 500`.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Comment: What IDE are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the display size to a larger value. According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html), `display.max_columns` defines the behavior taken when `max_cols` is exceeded. I'm not sure if this is referring to the number of columns, or the width of all columns. In either case, setting `display.width` to a larger value:

```
pd.options.display.width = 120
```

would probably fix your issue. The default is 80 characters, which is about what you have there before the value is written to a newline. If your editor is in a terminal window that you can resize, you could also try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
pd.options.display.max_columns = 500
```

I don't think `None` is an option for `display.max_columns`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work